# Tooltip not showing relevant data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a project where there is a list of 5 'Modules'(Module1, Module2... so on). Its displayed in a html table. Each module has some chapters in it and so when modules are displayed in the table, I need to make a tooltip so that when user hovers over the module name a small tooltip shows all the chapter titles associated with it. Pretty much successful in implementing this but stuck at a point where console is displaying message as 
`'Empty string passed to getElementById().'` and no chapters are being shown in tooltip and tooltip appears with "Please Wait..". 
Here is my code for the same,

this is my jQuery and AJAX,

```
 <link href='jquery-ui.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
      <script src='jquery-1.12.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
      <script src='jquery-ui.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 

   <script>  
      $(document).ready(function(){

 // initialize tooltip
 $( ".panel-body td" ).tooltip({
   track:true,
   open: function( event, ui ) {
   var id = this.id;
   var split_id = id.split('_');
   var module_id = split_id[1];

   $.ajax({
    url:'fetch_details.php',
    type:'post',
    data:{module_id:module_id},
    success: function(response){

    // Setting content option
    $("#"+id).tooltip('option','content',response);

   }
  });
  }
 });

 $(".panel-body td").mouseout(function(){
   // re-initializing tooltip
   $(this).attr('title','Please wait...');
   $(this).tooltip();
   $('.ui-tooltip').hide();
 });

});
</script>
```

And fetch_details.php

```
 <?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

    if(! $conn ) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
        echo '';
        mysql_select_db('dbname');

        $moduleid = $_POST['module_id'];

        $sql= mysql_query("SELECT title FROM table WHERE  module_id='$moduleid'");


        $html = '<div>';
        $i = 1 ;
        if( $sql === FALSE ) {
            trigger_error('Query failed returning error: '. mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
        } else {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $title = $row['title'];

                $html .= "<span class='head'>"<?php echo $title ; ?> " :</span><span>"" mins</span><br/>";
                $i++;
            }
        }
        $html .= '</div>';

    echo $html;

?>
```

Till now I am unable to find out what's going wrong with this . Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` variable is not accessible in the `success` function of ajax call.
You need to declare that as global variable in java-script.
Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

The other way is you can send the selected `id` to the post request and in response access in success function.

This is the ajax request you can make:

```
$( ".panel-body td" ).tooltip({
   track:true,
   open: function( event, ui ) {
   var id = this.id;
   var split_id = id.split('_');
   var module_id = split_id[1];

   $.ajax({
    url:'fetch_details.php',
    type:'post',
    dataType:'JSON'//change the response type to JSON
    data:{module_id:module_id,selected_id:id},
    success: function(response){
    // Setting content option
    //Access the selected and HTML variable from the response.
    $(response.selected_id).tooltip('option','content',response.html);

   }
  });
  }
 });

 $(".panel-body td").mouseout(function(){
   // re-initializing tooltip
   $(this).attr('title','Please wait...');
   $(this).tooltip();
   $('.ui-tooltip').hide();
 });

});
```

AND `fetch_details.php`

```
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $response=array();
    if(! $conn ) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
        echo '';
        mysql_select_db('dbname');

        $moduleid = $_POST['module_id'];
        $selected_id=$_POST['selected_id']; //get the selected id here
        $sql= mysql_query("SELECT title FROM table WHERE  module_id='$moduleid'");


        $html = '<div>';
        $i = 1 ;
        if( $sql === FALSE ) {
            trigger_error('Query failed returning error: '. mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
        } else {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $title = $row['title'];

                $html .= "<span class='head'>"<?php echo $title ; ?> " :</span><span>"" mins</span><br/>";
                $i++;
            }
        }
    $html .= '</div>';
    $response['html']=$html;
    $response['selected_id']=$selected_id;
    echo json_encode($response); 
    exit;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. But I am novice in Javascript and Ajax so can you help me how to implement this correctly.@MehtaSmit

Comment: @Ansh Check the edit section, I have updated the answer.Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks mate. Sorted this one. :)